# Gwt, CellTable, how can I know which column user clicks for sorting?

Tags: java, events, gwt

Writing GWT application.

I have CellTable and a code that i'v got from google-example code-site.

I need to implement server-side sorting by clicking on table's columns.

My code for that is:

```
AsyncDataProvider<MYOBJECT> dataProvider = new AsyncDataProvider<MYOBJECT>() {
 @Override
 protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<MYOBJECT> display) {
   final Range range = display.getVisibleRange();

   ...
   int sortingColumnIndex = 0;
   boolean isAscending = sortList.get(sortingColumnIndex).isAscending();

   // some server-side call here
 }
```

So, how can I know which column an user clicks on ? I.e. Real index of column of header of column or anything for identifying that column user clicked?

I have only **HasData display** as an event, but it seems is not enough to determinate the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sorting a CellTable server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272334/sorting-a-celltable-server-side/7272849#7272849)

The magic number 0, is the index of the sort column in the sort list, and not the column index from the cell table. 
So `sortList.get(0).getColumn()` gets you the column that the user clicked on. You have to worry about the other columns in the `sortList` only if you plan to implement sorting on multiple columns.

Comment: thx for that!. but the question still is not answered (see my addition fix in the question).

Comment: Once you get the column from the sortList, you can call table.getColumnIndex(sortColumn) to get the table index of the column. You can also keep a HashMap with the column as key and additional needed data as values.It's all in the link provided.

Comment: ok. thx. i did not recognize the link you provided, it's not enough blue, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
ColumnSortList sortList = dataTable.getColumnSortList();
Column<?, ?> column = sortList.get(0).getColumn();
```

Above will give you the required column.