# Multiple ColumnSorting with AsyncDataProvider

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2, gwt-celltable

I have sortable columns **A** and **B** . When user click on column **A** to sort , my result datas should sort via column **A** type and column **B** will show relative datas.When user was clicked on column **B** to sort , my result datas should sort via column **B** type and column **A** will show relative datas. I followed column sorting as [GWT Column Sort](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html#columnSorting) example by using [GWT DataGrid](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html) with [AsyncDataProvider](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/AsyncDataProvider.html). This example show single column sorting and I would like to use one or more column sorting but I don't know how to determine
 ***which column was fired column sort event ?***

At my RPC method ,

```
    AsyncHandler handler = new AsyncHandler(myGridTable);
    myGridTable.addColumnSortHandler(handler);
    myGridTable.getColumnSortList().push(A_column);
    myGridTable.getColumnSortList().push(B_column);

    AsyncDataProvider<AdminModel> provider = new AsyncDataProvider<AdminModel>() {
        protected void onRangeChanged(final HasData<AdminModel> display) {
            final int start = display.getVisibleRange().getStart();
            int length = display.getVisibleRange().getLength();

            AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String> {
                public void onFailure(final Throwable caught) {
                    Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
                }
                public void onSuccess(final String result) {
                    ........
                    updateRowData(start, adminList);
                }
            };
            final ColumnSortList sortList = myGridTable.getColumnSortList();
            // Here to determine which column sort

            // send request to server
        }
    };

    provider.addDataDisplay(view.getDataGridResults());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604211/gwt-celltable-how-can-i-know-which-column-user-clicks-for-sorting) for details.

Basically `view.getDataGridResults().getColumnSortList().get(0).getColumn()` will return the column the user clicked on.

If you want to get also the other columns (for example for multiple sorting) you have to check also the indices > 0 (i.e. `get(1).getColumn()`)

Once you have the column you can check the direction by calling `view.getDataGridResults().getColumnSortList().get(0).getColumn().isAscending()`

Comment: Now I can get **Column** sir  but how to know is it column **A** or **B** ? Pls help me sir . Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Fine , I got it bro... `Column<AdminModel, String> sortColumn = (Column<AdminModel, String>) sortList.get(0).getColumn();    myGridTable.getColumnIndex(sortColumn);`

Comment: column index can determine which type of column to be sorted. Thanks for your help bro.