# GWT column sort handler ,how to get column's value which has been selected

Tags: gwt, celltable

I have a celltable in GWT and want to implement sorting functionality on it , from database(Criteria)
for that i just want to know how to get the value of the column which has been clicked for sorting

here is my code

```
            ctJobs.addColumnSortHandler(new ColumnSortEvent.Handler() {
            public void onColumnSort(ColumnSortEvent event) { 
            event.getColumn();
            event.getColumn().getValue("what do we need to write here ???");
```

from event.getColumn() , i am getting column in the form of object

com.google.gwt.cell.client.ClickableTextCell@188a12e

I want to know the the column's name / value 
for that i am trying event.getcolumn().getvalue("??");
but what is the parameter for that, or is there any other way of getting column's name which has been clicked.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a `ListDataProvider` or an `AsyncDataProvider` for your cell table?

In case of an `AsyncDataProvider` the sorting must be done on the server side, so there is no need to add a `ColumnSortHandler`.

Please see the [GWT docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html#columnSorting).

To get the name of the column clicked for sorting see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272334/sorting-a-celltable-server-side/7272849#7272849).

Comment: thanks , in this scenario you mentioned it using comparator , but i want to sort it from the SQL side  , as below                  if(sortDirection.equals("asc")){
crit.addOrder(Order.asc(sortField));                                                            
  }           i just want to pass this string sortField when a user click on some column , isnt it possible to get the column name which has been selected?

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a link to the answer, that explains how to get the name of the sort column.

Answer (score 1):

When creating the table columns, set the dataStoreName of the column.

```
column.setDataStoreName("columnX");
```

Next, when in the AsyncDataProvider get the sort history of the clicked headers like the following

```
final AsyncDataProvider<SQLRow> dataProvider = new AsyncDataProvider<SQLRow>(){
    @Override
    protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<SQLRow> display) {
        for (int i=0;i<sortList.size();i++) {
            sortList.get(i).getColumn().getDataStoreName();
        }
    }
}
```